# Mutating an array without extra space

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

I was given the following question in an interview, and couldn't find the solution.

Given is an array of chars length **n**, and "important section" (all chars in this section must be saved) length **m** where **n >= m >= 0** as follows:

[image]

**Without extra space**, perform the following process:
Remove all occurrences of **A** and duplicate all occurrences of **B**, return a sub array of the mutated array. For example, for the above array `[C,A,X,B,B,F,Q]` n=7, m=5 ,output will be `[C,X,B,B,B,B]`. Note that the mutated array length is 6, since **Q** was in the redundant section and **B** was duplicated.

Return -1 if the operation can't be performed.

**Examples:**

```
n=2, m=2 , [A,B] => [B,B]  
n=2, m=2 , [B,B] => -1 (since the result [B,B,B,B] is larger then the array)  
n=3, m=2 , [A,B,C] => [B,B]  
n=3, m=3 , [A,B,C] => [B,B,C]  
n=3, m=2 , [Z,B,A] => [Z,B,B] (since A was in the redundant section)
```

Looking for a code example, Could this be done in O(n) time complexity?

Comment: Was the given array "dynamic" as you said "Remove all occurrences of A"?

Comment: What is the significance of `m`? Why not just ask, given an array of length `n`, remove all `a`s and duplicate all `b`s without using extra space? Is the only concern about `a`s and `b`s in the "redundant section"?

Comment: m is the length of the chars that must remain, any space behind m can be used for manipulation.

Comment: What is an answer for `[B,A,C,B,A,]`? And for `[B,C,A,B,A]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code, with some optimizations, would look something like this, O(n):

```java
// returns length of the relevant part of the mutated array or -1
public static int mutate(char[] a, int m) {
    // delete As and count Bs in the relevant part
    int bCount = 0, position = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        if (a[i] != 'A') {
            if (a[i] == 'B')
                bCount++;
            a[position++] = a[i];
        }
    }
    // check if it is possible
    int n = bCount + position;
    if (n > a.length)
        return -1;
    // duplicate the Bs in the relevant part
    for (int i = position - 1, index = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (a[i] != 'B') {
            a[index--] = a[i];
        } else {
            a[index--] = 'B';
            a[index--] = 'B';
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

1. Scan array to determine if is it possible to store mutated array in available space -- count `A`s and `B`, and check `N-M >= numB-numA`
2. Walk array left to right: Shift elements to the left by the number of `A`s so far (filling places of A)
3. Walk array right to left: Shift elements to the right by `numB-B_so_far`, inserting additional `B`s

Comment: What is the time-complexity of the solution?

Comment: could you add some code to your response, so I can accept it?

Comment: It is O(3n) = O(n). But you could do it with one iteration less. When passing the array the first time delete As and count only the Bs, then decide if it is possible and continue with step 3.

Comment: @Roni Gadot  I believe that everybody could implement such algorithm getting  valuable ideas ;-) (Note - this is algorithmic part of SO). Look at optimized version (steps 1 and 2 in a single run) from maraca

Comment: I agree, that the idea is the most important, otherwise you cannot code. But not only expressing a solution with comprehensible steps is an art-form, the translation of the words to code is too. There are infinite ways to do it, some more elegant than others, and especially for beginners this can be pretty hard.

Comment: @maraca I was hoping that author would try to code partially, at least 1st step (note - question was from interview). And yes, he/she can learn from your fine code.

Answer (score 2):

Start from the end of the input array. We will figure out from the back to the front what to fill in.

Look at the last significant character in the input (position `m`). If it is `a`, ignore it. Otherwise, add the symbol. Repeat until you read all the input.

This removes `a`s. Now we will duplicate `b`s.

Start from the beginning of the array. Find the last value you wrote during the above steps. If it is a `b`, write two `b`s. If it is something else, just write one of them. Repeat. NOTE: if you ever "catch up", needing to write where you need to read, you don't have enough room and you output `-1`. Otherwise, return the part of the array from position 1 to the last read position.

Example:

```
Phase 1: removing A
CAXBBFQ
CAXBBFB
CAXBBBB
CAXBXBB
CAXCXBB

Phase 2: duplicating B
CAXCXBB
CXXCXBB
CXBBXBB
CXBBBBB
^^^^^^
```

Phase 1 is linear (we read `m` symbols and write no more than `m`).

Phase 2 is linear (we read fewer than `m` symbols and write no more than `2m`).

`m` is less than `n` so everything is `O(m)` and `O(n)`.

Comment: could you add some code to your response, so I can accept it?